# Scheduler Multy jobs

Tags: c#, .net

Prompt how better to implement in the one object multiple jobs which perform different actions and that can be registered in the Scheduler to perform on schedule?

In general, the task to write Scheduler, that can to run several service at specified intervals.

Under the service meant different subsystems.
For example:

1. DataService - Automatic archiving data;
2. Adapter1 - First type of work;
   .......
3. AdapterK - K - type work;
4. Checker - Check queue and launch the desired Adapter;
5. Sender - Checking the queue and sending data;

All of the above subsystem already written. They need to add the ability to launch by timer.

Comment: Quartz might be your friend: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: What best HangFire or Quarz.NET?